# Doxygen - Linking a subpage depending on a page in the navigation tree

Tags: doxygen

I would like to add a link to a subpage in the navigation tree. It should appear as a child of its parent page.

```
+Mainpage
    +A
        -A1
        -A2
    +B
        -B1
        -B2
```

The upper "code" represents the navigation tree. A and B are pages and they have some information introducing their sons. A1 and A2 are sons of A, so they should be accessible from A, and they should be indexed in the navigation tree as subsections of A.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I would not mind if the solution links the A1 from the navigation menu directly to a text inside the page A. However, it should be possible to add this text anywhere in the page A and to use it as a subpage command (Hyperlink from A to A1)

Comment: Did you have a look at commands like `\page` and `\subpage` as well as `\ref`